# SharePoint modification forms in state machine workflows

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, state-machine, modification-form

I've been perplexed lately working on a SharePoint state machine workflow.  I was hoping to add some modification forms to the workflow so that I could reassign a task while in its state.  Unfortunately, modification forms don't seem to be documented for use with state machine workflows (pretty straight forward for sequence workflows though) anywhere that I can find.  The use of the ScopeHandlingActivity and its associated event handlers don't seem to mesh well with the state machine.

Has anyone gotten modification forms to work in a state machine workflow and how did you go about doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just modify task form and extend it by possibility to reassign task?

Answer (score 0):

First, I know this is a super old thread but since it was high on the search engine results I figured I'd put the solution here.

All you need to do is this with your Modification GUID:

1. Add EnableWorkflowModification activity in the workflow's Initial State
2. Add EventDriven activity to the WORKFLOW scope. This is the outer most border in the Design mode
3. Add OnWorkflowModification activity in that EventDriven activity

Additional Notes:

- GUID in the  tag MUST BE LOWERCASE
- Use a separate token for the modification activities that have the owner set as the Workflow itself so it's always in scope

Hope this answer is still useful for someone in the future!